# XCom.get_many is deprecated in Airflow 2.3

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

```
    execution_date=make_aware(datetime(2030, 4, 8, 0, 1, 00, 00)),
    dag_ids=[dag_id], 
    include_prior_dates=True,
    limit=3)
```

This was my code before upgrade.
now that get_many is deprecated how can I get the xcom values from previous run?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Airflow Models XCOM Official Docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/xcom/index.html) you can take a look at [get_value()](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/xcom/index.html#airflow.models.xcom.BaseXCom.get_value)

[Reading through the source](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/models/xcom.py), this essentially uses the XCOM.get_one() function.

Do you have any references to get_many() being depreciated? It is still present in the source code.

Final note from me, there is a new experimental [get_lineage function](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/api/common/experimental/get_lineage.py), which utilises get_many() under the hood.